# Small Facebook Likebox for Facebook Pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page, facebook-likebox

I noticed that buzzfeed is using an inline *button* to get fans for their Facebook page at the end of each article.
I'm wondering how they got this to work since the official Facebook guide lists only like *boxes* (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages).

Do you have any ideas how one could use this tiny version of the likebox?

[image]

Comment: That looks like it is just the normal Like button with the `data-href` attribute set to their Facebook page. You can test it out here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button by putting in a link to your Facebook page.

Comment: I thought something like this, I'm just wondering if this would work since I haven't found any official statements, have you?

Comment: It says it right [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) under the first step: "1. Choose URL or Page
Pick the URL of a website or Facebook Page you want to use with the like button."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tiny version you ask is the new like button, that can be customized a bit with form in Facebook developers page: [like-button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button)

In that case, `Include share button` check is unmarked and has `button_count` layout.

[image: Customizing like button]